# Python text file searching for values and compiling results found

Tags: python

I have a large text file of lots of experimental results to search through for specific pieces of data, which I need to compile. The text file has results from many different experiments, and I need to keep the data from each experiment together.

e.g. (Not the actual data)

```
Object 1

The colour of the object is blue.
The size of the object is 0.5 m^3
The mass of the object is 0.8 g

Object 2

The colour of the object is pink.
The size of the object is 0.3m^3
etc.
```

I know where the values I want will be, as I can search the text for a specific phrase that I know will be present on the line the data is on.

One way I thought of doing it would be to search through the file for each specific line (I'm looking for two different variables), and add the value needed to a list. From this I would then create a dictionary for each object, assuming that at the same number in each list will be data from the same object.

e.g.

```
variable_one = []
variable_two = []

def get_data(file):
    with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if "The colour" in line:
                variable_one.append(line.split()[6]) 
            if "The mass" in line:
                variable_two.append(line.split()[6]) 

        file.close()
```

or, to search through the file and create a list, with each entry being the section of data from a different object, then searching for the two variables for each object from within the different items in the list - again eventually storing the values from each object in a dictionary.

What I want to know is if there is a more efficient/better method for doing this than the ideas I had?

Comment: Small change - you don't need `file.close()` with a `with` statement, it closes it automatically!

Comment: Also, changing `"The colour" in line` to `line.startswith("The colour")` would firstly, mean slightly less of the line has to be searched, and secondly, lines that are invalid, but still contain "The colour" somewhere are ignored.

Oh, and why does the function take the argument `file`. It isn't used...

Comment: Is there are a regular interval between objects? In other words, can you count on a constant number of lines between the objects you are seeking? Also, are those objects named in predictable/consistent ways? If so, you might be able to `itertools.islice` (for slicing an iterable) the file and build your dictionary on the fly.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my code to line.startswith instead. user2387370.
Unfortunately erewok, there isn't regular intervals in my actual data. The text in the lines I'm searching for is predictable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative which uses only one list and uses less "append" and less "in" and thus should be more effective.

```
variables = []

with open('filename.txt') as input:
    colour = mass = ''
    for line in input:
        fields = line.split()
        if len(fields)>6:
            value = fields[6]
            if 'The colour' in line:
                colour = value
            elif 'The mass' in line:
                mass = value
        elif line.startswith('Object'):
            variables.append((colour, mass))
            colour = mass = '' # may not be needed.
del(variables[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The two object's I'm looking for in the output file are not in the same place in my actual data (sorry the example above was just a simplified version of the file I have to sort) - one is [3] and the other is [9] - but I could just remove the value variable and have colour = field[3] and mass = field[9]. However, I don't understand the reason for the 'if len(fields)>6' bit and the 'colour = mass = '' ' bit, could you explain? I'm still rather new to python.

Comment: `if len(fields) > 6:` means "if the length of `fields` is larger than 6, do everything in the indented block from the next line". `colour = mass = ''` means "set the variable `colour` to the variable `mass` to the empty string `''`". This has the effect of setting both the variables `colour` and `mass` to an empty string.

Comment: Do I use the `len(field)` bit just cut down on the amount of lines I search to save time? And why set `colour` and `mass` equal to an empty string at the start (is it just convention like in a counter when you set `count = 0` at the start)? 
And does the `elif` section mean that when the code finds a line beginning with `Object` - it adds the `colour` and `mass` from the previous objects data into a list? (thereby keeping each objects data separate?)

Comment: @user26608525 : Of course the code needs to be adapted to your data. Before you access the 7th field, you may want to check if there is a 7th field ; "if len(fields)>6" means "if there are at least 7 fields". Depending on your data, you may need to initialize the variables or not ... Try to delete "colour = mass = ''" and see ...

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it there looks fine to me in general, except for the areas I mentioned in the comments, and the indexing causing an error if you have a line shorter than 6 words.

Comment: Thank you. The line of text I'm looking for in my file will always be the same length, so I hope that won't be a problem.